# iOS 7 and TLS1.2 support

Tags: ios, ios7, tls1.2

Does iOS 7 supports TLS 1.2 by default? I was looking for a way to test my app on iOS 7 but no lucks so far.
Wondering if TLS 1.2 is supported by default on iOS7.

Thanks

Comment: You're actively developing for, and supporting a 6-year old mobile OS that the OEM does not support or offer assistance on?  Why iOS 7, I guess?

Comment: It’s a legacy project :(. We still have a handful of users we want to support.

Answer (score 2):

TLS 1.2 is supported from iOS 5, but it depends on what library/component/application are you using to connect your application to check if it's using TLS1.2 system libraries.

If you are trying to connect from Safari/iOS7, TLS 1.2 is supported as well.

Comment: Thanks, that was a legacy project and we still have a handful of users we want to support. The project used AFNetworking 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Yes. TLS 1.2 was adopted and made default in iOS 5. See the technical note explaining the problems that caused: [TN2287](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2287/_index.html)